# CVS -- Need command line to change status of file file from Binary to allow keyword substitution

Tags: binary, keyword, cvs

I am coming into an existing project after several years of use.  I have been attempting to add the nice keywords `$Header$` and `$Id$` so that I can identify the file versions in use.

I have come across several text files where these keywords did not expand at all.  Investigation has determined that CVS thinks these files are BINARY and will not expand the keywords.

Is there anyway from a Linux Command Line invocation to permanently change the status of these files in the repository to cause keyword expansion?  I'd be appreciative if you could tell me.  Several attempts that I have tried have not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cvs admin -kkv filename
```

will restore the file to the default text mode so keywords are expanded.

If you type

```
cvs log -h filename
```

(to show just the header and not the entire history), a binary file will show

```
keyword substitution: b
```

which indicates that keyword substitution is never done, while a text file will show

```
keyword substitution: kv
```

The `CVSROOT/cvswrappers` file can be used to specify the default new files you add, based on their names.

Comment: Do you have to checkin or commit the files once you do the admin command?

Comment: No. Of course the file has to be committed before you run `cvs admin`. But you can run `cvs log -h filename` after running `cvs admin ...` to make sure the update tool place.